# Cannot read property undefined in Angular

Tags: angular

I created the following service and component to get JSON object and print in the HTML.
When I'm trying to print a key of JSON data within html bind, it gives the correct result, but Console shows an Error saying "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {JsoncallItem} from "./jsoncall-item";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private postsURL ="http://myapp/browse/all/all";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {}
    getPosts(): Observable<JsoncallItem[]>{
      return this.http.get<JsoncallItem[]>(this.postsURL);
 }
}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from "./../search.service";
import { JsoncallItem } from "./../jsoncall-item";
import { error } from 'util';
import { SearchtermPipe } from './../searchterm.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'app';

    _postsArray: JsoncallItem[];

  constructor(private apiSerivce: ApiService){}

  getPosts(): void {
    this.apiSerivce.getPosts().
    subscribe(
       resultArray => this._postsArray = resultArray
       )
        //error => console.log("Error :: " + error ))
  }
  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getPosts();

  }
}
```

component.html

```
<p> {{_postsArray["data"]|json}} </p>
```

browse/all/all ==> JSON file

```
{ 
  A:1,
  B:2,
  C:3,
  data: 
   [
   {D:4},
   {E:5},
   {F:6}
   ]
}
```

What is the reason for receiving that error in console while getting the correct output?

Comment: I'm not sending the response to console log. When I execute this, I'm getting the correct result, but when Open the console by Inspect, there is the Error showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the value `_postsArray` is `undefined` at the beginning, until its value is loaded asynchronously. You could avoid seeing this error by changing your template to:

```
<p> {{_postsArray && _postsArray["data"]|json}} </p>
```

This way you first check if `_postsArray` is not undefined (truthy) before displaying the data.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get the error is because there's a typo either in your JSON file, or in your component template's file.

In your JSON file, you spelt `data` as `Data`. The solution is to either rename the `data` property in your component's template to `Data`, or rename the `Data` property in your JSON file to `data`.

P.S. Please check your property naming before opening a new question.

Comment: Thank you! Correction is done. JSON object has also 'data' and not 'Data'

Answer (score 1):

You should check your html with a *ngIf.

```
<p *ngIf="_postsArray">{{_postsArray["data"]|json}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a structural directive like *ngIf to check if the http request has returned the data before displaying it.

```
<p *ngIf="_postsArray"> {{_postsArray["data"]|json}} </p>
```

There are other better options like using the async pipe combined with an *ngIf: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-impure-asyncpipe

Answer (score 1):

Try checking both for null and undefined conditions for avoiding errors in all scenarios

```
<p *ngIf="_postsArray!=null&&_postsArray!=undefined">
{{_postsArray["data"]|json}} </p>
```